# ImageView width not scaled to fill ParentView in Autolayout iOS

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have tried to fill the `UIImageView` to fill the Image to be shown like a Top Header (logo). But it appears to have a 20px gap at the leading and trailing end.

I have used Leading and trailing constraints `0` but it shows 20 px gap (padding). If I'm using `-20` for leading and trailing contraints then it works well but the image seems to be stretched.

What should I do to overcome this weird issue?

I have even tried using Equal width contraints with Imageview and Parent View controller View, but still with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the current leading and trailing constraints. Add them again, but uncheck the `Constrain to margins` option, and now enter 0 for both leading and trailing constraints.

That should fix it.

[image]

Comment: That was awesome. Thanks for saving my day dzk

Comment: @user2695433 No problems!